# 2 php-fpm processes with the same version

Tags: php-fpm, apache2, xdebug

I would like to spawn two php-fpm processes (one with xdebug and one without) to make pages load faster

I intend to switch between php-fpm sockets based on the XDEBUG_SESSION cookie

Example code `/etc/apache2/conf-available/php7.2-fpm.conf`

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
  <If "%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM/">
          SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
  </If>
  <Else>
          SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001"
  </Else>
</FilesMatch>
```

I know how to configure php-fpm `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

But I have no idea how to spawn multiple (or just two) php-fpm processes.
If there is a simpler way, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `docker-compose` to switch between containers conditionally

https://github.com/unlocomqx/conditional-xdebug-fpm-docker

Inspired by
https://jtreminio.com/blog/developing-at-full-speed-with-xdebug/

Here are the interesting parts

Two separate php containers each with a different port and one without xdebug

```
  php:
    build:
      context: ./bin/php72-fpm
    container_name: '${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-${PHPVERSION}'
    volumes:
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
  php_xdebug:
    build:
      context: ./bin/php72-xdebug
    container_name: '${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xdebug-${PHPVERSION}'
    volumes:
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9002:9002"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a second php-fpm pool with the changed settings that you want. You only have one which you named `www`. Choose a different name for the second one.

Comment: But I read somewhere that you can't unload a php extension in a pool because the parent process already loaded it, I ended up using docker-compose to sort of switch between containers conditionally